# 3 Black Wires running out of a box into a switch

Tags: switch

So as the subject says... I've replaced a bathroom switch. The previous switch only controlled lights which is the way I want this one to operate as well.

The box has 3 wires coming to the switch all 3 are black.

After hooking the wires to the switch I end up being able to turn on my bathroom lights but when I do so it disables or turns off the closet lights.

I have tried to move the wires around in different combinations on the new switch and I still get either the same results or I get where the bathroom lights will come on and the closet lights will not operate at all.

I'm attaching pictures.
[image]
Thank you for your help..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiD0T.jpg)

Comment: Did the old switch have 3 screws?  Think about the light this switch *is supposed to* control.  Did it have 2 switches that operated it?  (I'm expecting "no" to both).

Comment: Did all the wires have hooks around the screws or was one stuck in the back of the switch?